# I've created a macro to check for any punctuation errors (spaces before commas, question marks etc.). Where do I put my loop?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to work out where to place my loop for grammar errors.

So this macro needs to loop through a document until it can no longer find any more of the searches (so as an example, it might find a space before a comma and remove that, but what if there were 2 spaces? It needs to loop back through once it's done the first find).

So once the loop completes it should look like:

" ,"
","

When I run this, I need all finds to be replaced.

The document should then be saved, a copy of it made and put into a different directory (not there with that yet - but if anyone can also help with that, it's referred to as strEbookFileName above) - so I know the loop needs to end BEFORE this, but I don't know if it should go inside the function or when the function is called.

Any help would be seriously appreciated!

```
Private Function FindReplace(docFind As Document, strFind As String, strReplace As String)

With docFind.Range.Find

.ClearFormatting
.Replacement.ClearFormatting
.Text = strFind

' SO!!! Should my loop be going here?
.Replacement.Text = strReplace
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


' MatchWilcards breaks it - work out how it all works
'.MatchWildcards = True

End With

End Function
```

```
Sub CleanUpFilesInFolder()

' - - - 1 - - -
' Variables
' Defined for FindAndReplace
Dim docEach As Document
Dim strFolder As String
Dim strFileName As String
Const strFileSUBPATH As String = "\Checked\"

' Defined for Ebook output folder
Dim strEbookFileName As String
Dim strEbookFolder As String
Const strEbookSUBPATH As String = "\Ebook\"

' - - - 2 - - -
' Directory locations

' Specify folder location - this contains location of the macro
strFolder = ThisDocument.Path & strFileSUBPATH
strFileName = Dir(PathName:=strFolder)

' Specify folder location - this contains output dir for Ebook files
strEbookFolder = ThisDocument.Path & strEbookSUBPATH
strEbookFileName = Dir(PathName:=strEbookFolder)


' - - - 3 - - -
' - - - B E G I N  P R O C E S S  - - -

' - - - S T E P  O N E - - -
' Process files in the Checked folder
' While the number of files is NOT 0
While strFileName <> vbNullString

' Open each file
Set docEach = Documents.Open(strFolder & strFileName)

' - - - S T E P  T W O
' - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
' Here you set exactly what you want to find and replace
' Enter what you're trying to FIND in between the FIRST two ""
' Enter what you're trying to REPLACE in between the SECOND two ""

'
'
'
' OR SHOULD I BE LOOPING EACH CALL OF FINDREPLACE?

     ' Remove blank line between paragraphs
     ' Call FindReplace(docEach, "^p^p", "^p")
     ' Call FindReplace(docEach, " ^p", "^p")

     ' Replace double spaces with a single space
     Call FindReplace(docEach, "  ", " ")

     ' space before , error
      Call FindReplace(docEach, " ,", ", ")

     ' space before . error
     Call FindReplace(docEach, " .", ". ")

     ' space before ? error
     Call FindReplace(docEach, " ?", "? ")

     ' space before ! error
     Call FindReplace(docEach, " !", "! ")


     ' space before ; error
     Call FindReplace(docEach, " ;", "; ")


     ' space before : error
     Call FindReplace(docEach, " :", ": ")

     ' space after ( error
     Call FindReplace(docEach, "( ", "(")

     ' space before ) error
     Call FindReplace(docEach, " )", ")")

     ' space after " error
     ' T O  D O - Fucks up when you enable WildCards
     ' Call FindReplace(docEach, """ "", """"")


     'Capital letter after .
     ' T O  D O
     'Call FindReplace(docEach, ". [a-z]", ". [A-Z]", Start:=0)

     ' Replace two hyphens with em dash
     Call FindReplace(docEach, "--", "-")



' Save a copy of the file and close the file
' and add ability to copy file to Ebook dir AFTER changes have been made
' Not right - ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=(Ebook & strFileName)

docEach.Close SaveChanges:=True

' Once all finds have been replaced, save a copy of each doc
' in the Ebook directory and
' Move on to next file

strFileName = Dir

Wend


End Sub
```

Comment: These are punctuation errors, not grammar errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're over-complicating things, IMHO. Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = " ([.,:;\?\!\)\}\]])"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1 "
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "([\(\{\[]) "
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "--"
    .Replacement.Text = "^+"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "[ ]{2,}"
    .Replacement.Text = " "
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

No loops required.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with following modification and it is performing what so far I understand it supposed to do.

```
Private Function FindReplace(docFind As Document, strFind As String, strReplace As String)
    Do                           ' loop added
    With docFind.Range.Find

    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = strFind

    ' SO!!! Should my loop be going here?
    .Replacement.Text = strReplace
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


    ' MatchWilcards breaks it - work out how it all works
    '.MatchWildcards = True
    If .Found = False Then Exit Do   ' Line Added
    End With
    Loop
End Function
```

in the Sub `CleanUpFilesInFolder` commented out the line to avoid `Dir`command

```
'strEbookFileName = Dir(PathName:=strEbookFolder)
```

and near to the end of `Dir` Loop

```
'docEach.Save              ' May save changes in original files according to your choice
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
docEach.SaveAs strEbookFolder & strFileName
docEach.Close False
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll

strFileName = Dir
Wend
```

Comment: on 2nd thought, it may be more efficient if  the `Do` loop is used only with `Call FindReplace(docEach, "  ", " ")`. It would replace all multiple spaces  with single space and other replacements would not be required to run in loop.  The function code with `Do` loop may be used directly in the Sub `CleanUpFilesInFolder` for replacing multiple spaces  with single space and the function may keep as original (without do loop) for better efficiency.